# Replacement Alternative for Dell FY606 in a Poweredge T105

Tags: raid, hard-drive, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid

I have recently upgraded my Poweredge T105 server to use a SAS 6/ir RAID controller.  Unfortunately, I did not realize at the time that adding the card would cause the BIOS to complain about a missing hard drive fan.  This warning requires that a user press F1 to continue, which is disastrous in a server environment.

I have searched all over found that the specific part I need is a Dell FY606 fan.  However, I have yet to find a suitable retailer that covers this part.  I have contacted Dell and they do not have this part in stock.  Are there any alternative models of a fan that I could use in place of an FY606?  Seems like a pretty straightforward part, just a fan that connects to a 4-pin power connector on the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try asking Dell Support for part 400-14766 - FY606 is apparently an internal Dell part number.

(Source: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/p/19136708/19773067.aspx#19773067)

It's probably a standard PWM fan but you need the bracket if you want it held in the right place, and I'm 90% certain it'll have a Dell proprietary connector on it.

Comment: I contacted Dell replacement parts again and provided the alternate part number you gave me.  They still told me it was not available and told me that I could search for part FY606 online to find a third party retailer.

Comment: Dell can be supremely useless when they want to be, can't they? Have you tried these guys? http://www.impactcomputers.com/fy606.html

Answer (score 0):

> However, I have yet to find a suitable retailer that covers this part.

I'll bet that you can get the part from Dell. Why are you looking elsewhere without calling them first?

Comment: Because I have called them first and I was told that the part was not in stock.